# fatal: 'jigar/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a server which has centos 6 and it is running GITLAB .I am on my local pc in a network with static IP , now i want to push my local repository to GitLAb which has SSH and HTTPS link . But whenever i push to the server it shows

```
**[root@hardik adarshcr7]# git push origin HEAD:master
git@192.168.1.10's password: 

fatal: 'jigar/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.**
```

Please help me out its almost two weeks i am trying and make Gitlab work in the network.
There other computers too connected in the network through Cyberaom.

Comment: For questions regarding network services and connectivity issues there are [ServerFault @ SE](http://serverfault.com/) and [SuperUser @ SE](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @AntonSamsonov but this is not about connectivity, but most likely about not having created the repo upfront in the web interface

Comment: @Vampire Yeah, and that is why I mentioned network *services* (i. e. git server configuration, including all its aspects like repository settings, file permissions, other system-level security measures) in the first place. However, the thing that reminded me of network connectivity is that `192.168.1.10` — it may be not the server running GitLab, but some other machine with the same user accounts.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov I don't see how you get this idea? Just because no DNS name is used, but the GitLab servers IP?

Comment: @Vampire Exactly! It is a very common error (in the general sense, not specific to Git), even when IP addresses are static. The server does not even need to have a similar filesystem layout, — the error message would be the same for any missing path.

Comment: I still don't get what you are saying. His error is not some missing file in the filesystem or some network problem, but that he used the GitLab software wrongly.

Comment: @AntovSamsonov I didnt get this idea i am new to Gitlab its already setup on server . so to access it i put url as 192.168.1.10:83 the page which shows up is **Gitlab Community Edition** Username and password for sign in

Comment: Friends i tried to push and clone from other system it worked perfectly, i push and cloned successfully. 
But i have to figure out why i am not able do pull and clone on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message says there is not Git repository named `test` for the user `jigar`. So go to the Gitlab web interface and create the repository before you try to push to it.

---

**Update:**
As you say you did create the repo in the web interface and cloning / pushing works from another machine, I suspect you authenticate as a different user that does not have the right to see this repository. Try running `ssh git@192.168.1.10` on the machine where it does not work and GitLab will tell you as which user you identified. Give that user access to the repo in the web interface or remove your SSH key from the user you are authenticating as and add your key to the user that has access instead in the web interface.

Comment: First of all i am new to gitlab and i have created a repository by clicking on **New project** named it as test on Gitlab web interface which gives me link

**SSH : git@192.168.1.10:jigar/test.git

**HTTPS=https://git@192.168.1.10/jigar/test.git**

Push pull and clone option doesn't work gives me the above mentioned error.